# Pascal's Triangle by recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int Pascal_Tri(int row , int col)
{
    if (row==col || col==0)
        return 1 ;
    else
    {
        return Pascal_Tri(row-1,col)+Pascal_Tri(row-1,col-1);
    }

}
```

there is a problem with this code and I can not discover it.
when I run it, the program stops working and no results disappear

Comment: what inputs are you giving it? if you give `col > row`, it will never end.

Comment: col =3 , row = 3

Comment: then how will it run, it will return 1 and exit.

Comment: what should i do to print the triangle ?

Comment: check  [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pascal-triangle/) out. They explain the step by step process. I don't think you need a recursive function by the way

Comment: the question needs to do it by recursion :(

Comment: Oh! I thought so. why would someone go out the way to do it using recursion. wait i will make up something

Comment: this link uses loops and I just want to use recursive function ...... no loops, no multiplication and no call to factorial function

Comment: If you want to print the _entire_ triangle, then why are you taking two inputs? You should just give it the row. However, I would guess that your task is _computing_ each number only with recursion - _printing_ the triangle properly is quite difficult if you're not allowed to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

**C++11**

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <vector>                                                               
std::vector<int> pascal(int height, std::vector<int> curr)                      
{            
    for(int i=0; i<curr.size(); i++)                                            
        std::cout<<curr[i]<<" ";                                                
    std::cout<<std::endl;                                                                    
    if(height<=0)                                                               
        return curr;                                                            
    std::vector<int> newCurr(curr.size()+1,1);                                  
    for(int i=0; i+1 < curr.size(); i++)                                        
            newCurr[i+1] = curr[i] + curr[i+1];                                 

    return pascal(height-1,newCurr);                                            
}                                                                               

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    int row, col;                                                               
    std::cin>>row>>col;                                                         
    std::vector<int> rowPascal = pascal(row,std::vector<int>{1});               
    std::cout<< rowPascal[col];                                                 
}
```

With the driver function to test. I know it's not very efficient but it should do!

This will basically give you the number at a specific row ( from the top) and a specific col (from the left) in the pascal's triangle . (both zero indexed)

Comment: when col=3 and row =3 , it outputs 3

Comment: I said zero indexed.  use row =2 and col=2.

Comment: it outputs only 1

Comment: yeah, that's what you wanted right? to get a specific number at a particular column and row? otherwise why you would make a function that accepts both row and col!

Comment: use this instead. that's the best i can do. you can customize the program if you want something else

Comment: row and col which i take is the number of row and col of the triangle which i want to print on screen

Comment: it's a pascal triangle. if you give row the column is essentially fixed. Anyways, the above code should print what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's unreasonably difficult to print the triangle without using loops, here is a solution that uses your purely recursive `Pascal_Tri` function to compute the numbers but prints them with a loop:

```
int rowsToPrint = 5;

for (int row = 0; row < rowsToPrint; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <= row; ++col)
        std::cout << Pascal_Tri(row, col) << ",  ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/brchVOiC1jQkX1bF)